# How do I set a mp4 as my background?

Tags: animation

Ok so i got this template from the internet, and it came with an mp4 file called shockwave, everything worked, but I dont know how to add that shockwave behind the text. here is how it suppose to look.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8WKpitwn4Q

- Time where it shows it: 0:13 - 0:14

and right now i got the text and the audio working. I just need the shockwave to show on the background.
If someone can help, i would appreciate it a lot!!!
Thanks!

Comment: Upload .blend File?

Comment: Would you like to use the background as a reference while modelling or in the final shot?

Comment: @parameciostudio in the final shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine a 3D Scene with a video using different tools:

### Node Editor (Compositing)

**PRO:** Here you can apply filters, color correction, and other cool effects.

**CONS:** Non-linear editing is a little complicate

Some tips:

1. Set alpha mode **Transparent** in the Render Panel
2. Toggle **Compositing** in the Render Panel
3. Scale the Movie Clip to fit the render dimensions

[image: Node Editor]

### VSE (Video Sequence Editor)

**PRO:** Easy control over the timeline

**CONS:** Little effects

Some tips:

1. Select the Scene Strip and set Blend to **Alpha Over**
2. Toggle **Sequencer** in the Render Panel

[image: VSE]

This is only an overview: you'll find a lot of tutorial on the web about Node Compositing and VSE (Video Sequence Editor)

Comment: Wow, im surprised!!! Thanks for that, it worked like I wanted to. Can I count of you if I have other questions? I appreciate all you did, you know what you are doing, YOU A PRO!!!

Comment: Oh and btw, I'll like your answer once i get 15 REP.

Comment: Galde to help you! This is an active community where people share their knowledge and experience. I learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0):

In your 3D Viewport, press [N] and a pop-up will come out on the side. Scroll down on it, and it has a box labeled "Background Images". Enable this by clicking the black box on it, and there you can choose between selecting the background to be an image, or a movie file. :D

Comment: Hey I appreciate your answer, but the video don't wanna show,any idea on how to make it show and how to set it at a specific time, like lets say staring at frame #9 of the animation.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for trying to help, that didint work, but you still tried, thats what counts!

Comment: That will set the [background shown in the viewport](http://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/background_images.html), which is only visible in orthographic view in presets eg Front, Side, Top. The question is about a video as part of the final render.

Comment: @sambler Thx for explaining that in detail 